# Chrome Dev Tools - Unable to map network file to local file

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome Dev tools, I am no longer able to map a localhost network file to the  local source file for saving changes to disk. The problem occurs when I click on [Map to file system resource...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9UvjJ.png).  It does not populate [the next screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2W6z.png) with local file choices as it used to. Any help or hints are much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should delete the "?ver=4.7.2" - these are query parameters which confuse the search for local files.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried that. And yes, it then populates the next screen, allowing me to select the local file. But clicking on it still doesn't successfully map it (and allow me to save changes). However since your suggestion does enable selection of the proper file, I think perhaps I'm now dealing with a different problem.

Comment: Andrey, I think you answered the question I asked. I appear to be mapping the files but I still can't save them as I used to be able to. I might be missing something basic but I think it's a different issue so I want to give credit where it's due and move on. I'll formulate a new question if I can't figure it out.

Comment: Wade, current DevTools workspace implementation has troubles with mapping such files, see crbug.com/277885 for more details. However, you can try enabling "Persistence2.0" experiemnt in devtools which should solve this and other mapping problems

Comment: Could you please file a bug on crbug.com/new and explain what doesn't work for you? I would be happy to help!

Comment: I went to reproduce the failure and it worked this time! Perhaps I did something wrong when I tried it earlier. Another solution I found was to install the Wordpress plugin "Remove Query Strings From Static Resources". So now I have 2 solutions! Thanks again for your help.